# Polygon color on intersect

Tags: openlayers-2, intersection, color

Using OpenLayers, I am loading a large geojason file of about 4000 polygons.

Once the polygons are loaded I want to draw a "LineString" on the map (already done and working).

**My challenge is that I want to change the color of the polygons that intersects with the drawn line.**

My research did not return any information that would guide me for this feature.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: What if the lines are drawn and the only need is to select line, and automatically polygons are selected?

Answer (score 1):

Here http://acanimal.github.io/Openlayers-Cookbook at Chapter08-Selecting features intersecting with a line you can find a sample of control that selects the features that intersects with a line.

The code is at https://github.com/acanimal/Openlayers-Cookbook and the concrete code for the control at https://github.com/acanimal/Openlayers-Cookbook/blob/master/recipes/ch08/selectFeaturePath.js#L49

The main task is to check, with the linestring method `intersect`, if the linestring intersects with any of features of the desired layer.

```
    for(var l=0; l<layers.length; ++l) {
        layer = layers[l];
        for(var i=0, len = layer.features.length; i<len; ++i) {
            var feature = layer.features[i];
            // Check if the feature is displayed
            if (!feature.getVisibility()) {
                continue;
            }

            if (this.geometryTypes == null || OpenLayers.Util.indexOf(
                this.geometryTypes, feature.geometry.CLASS_NAME) > -1) {
                if (**path.intersects(feature.geometry)**) {
                    if (OpenLayers.Util.indexOf(layer.selectedFeatures, feature) == -1) {
                        this.select(feature);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Cheers.